# Make text in ajax generated input field selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't make text in ajax generated input field selectable on click.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="url" value="">
<script>
$.ajax({
...
element.append('<input type="text" id="test" value="' + 'https://' + location.host + '/' + data[0].data + '">')
}
});
return false;
});
</script>
<script>
$('input').on('focus', function (e) {
    $(this)
        .one('mouseup', function () {
            $(this).select();
            return false;
        })
        .select();
});
</script>
```

I can select all text on click in #url input, beside text in ajax generated input. 
All I want is to make text in both static inputs and ajax generated inputs selected on click.

Comment: `$(document).on('focus', 'input', function (e) {}` Will also add the listener to dynamically created elements, is this what you're after?

Comment: Ajax added elements are not in the jquery aware dom right away. So do $(document).find('input')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('focus', 'input', function () {
    $(this).select();
});
```